# xamarin: Can not find a property named "HasBackButton" or static method named "GetHasBackButton"

Tags: xamarin.android

```
<ContentPage Title="Introduction"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xamarin.IntroductionPage">
```

I see some other video tutorials, they have no problem with NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False" but on my Visual Studio with Xamarin it produces build error

```
Can not find a property named "HasBackButton" or static method named "GetHasBackButton" ...
```

what could be causing this? thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm also seeing this same problem.  Appears to be the XAMLC compiler not dealing with attached properties correctly for some reason.  If you have a XamlCompilation attribute at the assembly level you can comment it out and the problem will go away until a proper solution is found.

After more research I've found that XAMLC must have changed recently and now expects the first parameter on the Get/Set methods for attached bindable properties to be of type BindableObject.  Unfortunately NavigationPage.GetHasBackButton and NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton both expect a Page as their first parameter.  Since NavigationPage is provided by the platform the only work arounds appear to be commenting out the XamlCompilation attribute or removing the NavigationPage.HasBackButton line in your XAML and moving it to code behind where it will compile with no problem:

```
public class MyContentPage : ContentPage  
{  
    InitializeComponent();  

    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton( this, false );  
}
```

Hopefully Xamarin will provide a fix for this regression soon.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.

Removing `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in the *.cs did the trick.